# DAX code to find custom Week Start Date and Week End Date

Tags: date, powerbi, dax

I have a custom DateTable. It starts with March till Dec only , so there is no Jan and Feb. It can be multiple years. The dates between 1st Mar till 7th Mar is Week Number 1 and then it moves on. The DateTable can be created using the following DAX code:

`DateTable =  ADDCOLUMNS ( FILTER ( CALENDAR ( DATE ( 2019, 3, 1 ), DATE ( 2025, 12, 31 ) ), MONTH ( [Date] ) >= 3 && MONTH ( [Date] ) <= 12 ), "Month Name", FORMAT ( [Date], "MMM" ), "Year", YEAR ( [Date] ), "Month Number", MONTH ( [Date] ), "Quarter", "Q" & INT ( ( MONTH ( [Date] ) - 1 ) / 3 ) + 1, "Campaign Week Number", IF( MONTH([Date]) = 3 && DAY([Date]) <= 7,  1,  WEEKNUM([Date] - DATE(YEAR([Date]), 3, 1)+1, 1) ) )`

The problem is I need to find out the Week Start Date and Week End Date. For example:

For the Week Number 1 the date range would be 01-03-2023 till 07-03-2023 and the Week Start Date should be 01-03-2023 and the Week End Date should be 07-03-2023. These Start and End dates should be the same for all the dates between 1st March and 7th March but when the date becomes 8th March then it will be changed and the Week Start Date will become 08-03-2023 and Week End Date will become 14-03-2023.

The above DateTable works fine so either these two values can be added as columns or I can be happy to use them as Measure also.

Can anyone help me with this problem but please first test at your end and then suggest the solution?

I have tried measure but it gives me the wrong Date:

`Week End Date =
VAR currentCampaignWeek = [Current Week Number]
VAR currentYear = YEAR(TODAY())

Return
CALCULATE(MAXA(DateTable[Date]),FILTER('DateTable', DateTable[Campaign Week Number] = currentCampaignWeek && DateTable[Year] = currentYear))`

The above code is giving me 12-04-2023 although it should have given me 18-04-2023.

I have used another measure in the above code which is working fine:

`Current Week Number =  VAR currentDate = TODAY() RETURN CALCULATE( MAX(DateTable[Campaign Week Number]), FILTER(DateTable, DateTable[Date] <= currentDate && DateTable[Year] = YEAR(currentDate)) )`